# How can I fix "Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function." message when I call "GetIsNetworkAvailable"?

Tags: c#

I'm using "GetIsNetworkAvailable" function for internet connection check.
This code generate "Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function" messages so many time per one calling.
How can I fix or hide this messages

This is not error in C#, just debugging message.
But, It's very annoying.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

public static bool IsConnectedToInternet()
{
    return InternetGetConnectedState(out int Desc, 0) && System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
}
```

I don't want see "Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function" messages.

Comment: Try declaring `int desc = 0;` and passing it to the function (even though it should work anyway). Why do you have a call to both `InternetGetConnectedState` and `GetIsNetworkAvailable()`? Both not so much reliable. Try  [INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetworklistmanager-getconnectivity). It's much more verbose on what is connected and what is not. `NetworkListManager` is a COM library, you need to add a reference to the Project to use it.

Comment: I mean: `int desc = 0; return InternetGetConnectedState(out desc, 0)`.